# How to get the closest value to a list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, lambda, python-itertools

I have a quite big list which contains a lot of data. I'am trying to get the `min` `x[-2]` in that list if its `>= limit`.

This is my list: [enter link description here](https://pastebin.com/gvB2VVKK)

**This is my code:**

```
limit = 45.7

ls_list = []
for key,sublists in itertools.groupby(my_list,lambda y:y[0]): 
    v = min(x for x in sublists if float(x[5].replace(',', '.')) >= limit);
    ls_list.append(v[-2])

print(ls_list)
```

**This is my output:**

```
[137.332]
```

If you check out `my_list` you can see that `45,705` in `x[5]` should
actually be the `min(>= limit)` so it should grab the `x[-2]` which in that row. Right now it grabs the `x[-2]` of the whole list...

**Expected output is:**

```
[148.419]
```

Please note that I use the `groupby` function because the originally
`my_list` also contains values from `C150, C151, C152` etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now the `min` function sorts the list from `x[0]` and onwards. Suppose you have a list like:

```
a = [['a', 'x', 'r', 5, 1],
     ['a', 'x', 'r', 2, 3],
     ['a', 'x', 'r', 4, 5],
     ['a', 'x', 'r', 3, 6]]
```

So if you run `min(a)` it will give `a[1]` as all the elements in all the `sublists` are equal before the 4th element, so `min` is based on this element.

In your case, since all the elements of the sublists at indices 0, 1, 2 and 3 are exactly same, that's why `min` returns the list which has the minimum value in the 4th index. And this turns out to be the last sublist in my_list.

Try this:

```
v = min((x for x in sublists if float(x[5].replace(',', '.')) >= limit), key=lambda x: x[-1])
```

What the `key=lambda...` function in above line will do is, it will force the `min` to find minimum based on the last element of each sublist.

Or you can also take just the intended values from which you want to compute minimum i.e.:

```
v = min(x[-1] for x in sublists if float(x[5].replace(',', '.') >= limit)
```

But this will append the value from x[5] or x[-1] and not from x[-2]. The above approach with lambda will give the expected output.

Comment: When I tried your first one i got the same result. When I tried your second one I got:   `ls_list.append(v[-2])
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Try the first one again I've made an update to the error which I made earlier. Sorry for that:)

Comment: Aha! Your first one worked... But now I need to know what actually happened. Could you try and break the code up so I know exactly what was going wrong?

Comment: I've tried to explain it somewhat more, hope it would be clear now:)

Comment: By the way, only this line `min((x for x in my_list if float(x[5].replace(',', '.')) >= limit), key=lambda x: x[-1])[-2]` would also do the work. But since you say grouping is necessary, this might not work out perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

```
limit = 45.7
import math
[i[4]  for i in my_list if math.isclose(float(i[5].replace(',','.')),limit, rel_tol=0.001)]
```

You can use `math` module which has `isclose()` method

[math.isclose(a, b, *, rel_tol=1e-09, abs_tol=0.0)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose)

> Return True if the values a and b are close to each other and False
> otherwise.
>
> Whether or not two values are considered close is determined according
> to given absolute and relative tolerances.
>
> rel_tol is the relative tolerance – it is the maximum allowed
> difference between a and b, relative to the larger absolute value of a
> or b. For example, to set a tolerance of 5%, pass rel_tol=0.05

Output:

```
[148.419]
```